# External monitor connection cause Ubuntu (20.04.2) freeze

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 4k-monitor

Setup:

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64bit
Intel® Core™ i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz × 12 
NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P1000 Mobile] (P1000 [Zbook Studio G5 mobile workstation])
```

A few days ago I hade my laptop connected through USB-C to my Dell 38" 4k monitor and all was working fine. Then I had some updates (which I did not recall what they were, I just installed them as I usually do with recommended updates). Some day later when I rebooted the reboot seemed to hang at shutting down so I hard reset the laptop. After that, the laptop will get stuck att boot or, if I start up without the USB-C screen cable connected, Ubuntu freezes when I connect the cable.

I try to recall anything else out of the ordinary that I have done and the only thing I can come to think of is having almost closed the lid (just to make the screen go black, without risking to trigger any sleep mode or so).

Working without the external screen is a pain in the ass so I would very much appreciate any help. Perhaps there has been a kernel update or graphics driver update that is not compatible, but I have not found out how to find out when they were updated.

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-74-generic

$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Jun  9 07:42:26 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P1000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P3    N/A /  N/A |    576MiB /  4031MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1356      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3089      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                244MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3293      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              165MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3724      G   ...gAAAAAAAAA --shared-files       15MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3901      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       25MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4233      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       73MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9468      G   /usr/bin/nvidia-settings            0MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10367      G   gnome-control-center                1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am not really used to this kind of troubleshooting at all so please ask for more information if needed.

EDIT:

```
$ less /var/log/apt/history.log
...
Start-Date: 2021-06-03  06:33:51
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: libnvidia-common-460:amd64 (460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, automatic)
Upgrade: libnvidia-common-450:amd64 (450.119.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 460.80-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
End-Date: 2021-06-03  06:33:51
```

If I interpret this log correctly there has fairly recently been an update from version 450 to 460 of nividia-common. Is there any way to roll back this update?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the solution was to go into bios and select UMA graphics.